# UIScrollView Not Working When Page Is Reloaded

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I'm having an issue with a UIScrollView implementation. The first time the view is loaded, the scrollView works fine. However, when I move to another view with a navigation drawer and then come back to the original view, the scrollView no longer scrolls but still contains content.

The UIScrollView which contains UITextFields and UIButtons pragmatically created at run time. The views are created within the `viewDidLoad()` function and then added to a parent view which is then added to the scrollView. Because the size of the scroll content varies at run time, this is set programmatically in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.accountCardView.frame.width, self.cardHeight.constant + 15)
}
```

In this code sample, the cardHeight variable is a constraint containing the height of the main view in the scrollview. This is the view which contains the textFields and buttons.

I have placed a debug point within the viewDidLayoutSubviews() function to observe the cardHeight variable. The cardHeight is consistent every time the page is loaded and should set the scrollView content size properly.

I have also tried redrawing the views within the `viewWillAppear()` function but observed the same results.

Does anyone have ideas as to why the scroll view does not work when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Check the scroll view's frame. It may not be laid out properly so its subviews extend beyond its bounds, therefore making you unable to interact with the scroll view or its subviews.

Comment: Like Adam suggested, you might want to check the actual scrollView frame itself (not the contentSize) to ensure it's within the screen size. Also, just out of curiosity, will it work if you add `self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true`?

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I tried setting the scrollEnabled to true in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() function this did not change the behavior. I have also checked the frame size vs the content size: Frame width = 315 Frame height = 437.5 Content height = 474. So in this case the content is taller than the scrollView which is necessary for it to scroll correct?